# Ifelse in R with missing variables

Tags: r, if-statement

1.Using the following columns:

```
s1 <- c(1,2,4,2,3,4,2,3)
s2 <- c(2,3,1,1,4,3,3,5)
s3 <- c(3,4,2,4,1,2,1,4)
s5 <- c(4,1,3,3,2,1,4,2)
s6 <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1)
samples <- cbind(s1, s2, s3, s5, s6)
samples <- data.frame(samples)
```

2. I generate the following code:

```
samples$r1<-ifelse(samples$s1==1,"s1", 
ifelse(samples$s2==1,"s2",
ifelse(samples$s3==1,"s3",
ifelse(samples$s5==1,"s5",        
ifelse(samples$s6==1,"s6",       
"99")
))))
```

3. Which gives me the following result.

```
 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 r1
1  1  2  3  4  5 s1
2  2  3  4  1  5 s5
3  4  1  2  3  5 s2
4  2  1  4  3  5 s2
5  3  4  1  2  5 s3
6  4  3  2  1  5 s5
7  2  3  1  4  5 s3
8  3  5  4  2  1 s6
```

4. So far, so good...
5. I then add another condition to the code on variable s4....

```
samples$r1<-ifelse(samples$s1==1,"s1", 
ifelse(samples$s2==1,"s2",
ifelse(samples$s3==1,"s3",
**ifelse(samples$s4==1,"s4",**        
ifelse(samples$s5==1,"s5",
ifelse(samples$s6==1,"s6",       
"99")
)))))
```

6. ...which does not exists in the dataset. I now get the following results

```
 s1 s2 s3 s5 s6   r1
1  1  2  3  4  5   s1
2  2  3  4  1  5 <NA>
3  4  1  2  3  5   s2
4  2  1  4  3  5   s2
5  3  4  1  2  5   s3
6  4  3  2  1  5 <NA>
7  2  3  1  4  5   s3
8  3  5  4  2  1 <NA>
```

7. No error message is recoreded, but the presence of a new variable, s4, in the 
code that does not exist in the data set creates an error in the output as I get    r1= NA , when I should have expected an identical output to the one in point 3 above. The inclusion of a non-existent variable in the code caused this error, and I struggle to find a way to get around it. In ORACLE SQL I would have used "case when exists" but this option is not possible in the SQLDF package in R. 
7. This is a simplified version of a real life problem where I need to write code that is able to run smoootly even tohugh the input variables will differ from time to time. Hence, while the column S4 was not in this dataset, it may appear in the next dataset I run this code on, so I have to make room for that eventuality.

8. I have tried to use:

   samples$r1<-ifelse(exists(samples$s1==1,"s1"), 
   ifelse(exists(samples$s2==1,"s2"),
   ifelse(exists(samples$s3==1,"s3"),
   **ifelse(exists(samples$s4==1,"s4"),**
   ifelse(exists(samples$s5==1,"s5"),
   ifelse(exists(samples$s6==1,"s6"),
   "99")
   )))))

but this is evidently too simple and does not help me with this problem. I have also searched Stack Overflow in great measures without finding a solution to this problem.  '?Exists' in R does not either as far as I can tell provide me with the help I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to revise your question, i.e. use proper formatting for code blocks, minimize your example, correct the errors (e.g. I get `Error in cbind(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5) : object 's4' not found` when running your initial lines), and focus and the actual problem. It's hard to read/follow the way it stands.

Comment: Luke, I was a bit uncertain as to how much to write in addition to the actual question. I take it your advice is to state the question only and leave it at that. I'll keep that in mind. Anyway, the problem was solved by Martin below.

Comment: Afaik, to get good answers fast on SO, it's best to a.) provide example input data, b.) desired output data, c.) the code you tried incl. required library calls and a note in what way it failed. Plus d.) cut out the fat where you can (= minimal code, minimal data, minimal description), focus on one problem at a time and make sure this problem/question stands out immediately. Most people skim posts, they don't read through "biographies" ;) But that's just my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bounded to use nested `ifelse` statements you can try

```
dt$r1 <- apply(dt, 1, function(x) {
  names(which(x == 1))
})

   s1 s2 s3 s5 s6 r1
1:  1  2  3  4  5 s1
2:  2  3  4  1  5 s5
3:  4  1  2  3  5 s2
4:  2  1  4  3  5 s2
5:  3  4  1  2  5 s3
6:  4  3  2  1  5 s5
7:  2  3  1  4  5 s3
8:  3  5  4  2  1 s6
```

Or you could go with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(samples)
dt[, r1 := colnames(dt)[max.col(-dt)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: use one of Martin Schmelzer's solutions in your actual problem.

But answering to your problem as proposed:

Your code in item (8) would not run, because `ifelse()` needs 3 parameters (and you provided only 2) and `exists()` does not do what I think you are expecting it to do (as implied by your code).

You pass as parameter to `exists()` a string with the name of a variable to look for (and optionally an environment or object within which to search) and it returns whether or not exists a variable with that name, and never its value.  In your example, it would be `exists("s4", samples)`, and not `exists(samples$s4)`, but it would only return `FALSE`.

```
> teste <- list(x = 1:3)
> teste
$x
[1] 1 2 3
> exists("x", teste)
[1] TRUE
> exists("teste$x")
[1] FALSE
```

`get0()` is more likely to do what you want

```
> get0("teste$x")
NULL
> get0("x", teste)
Error in get0("x", teste) : argumento 'envir' inválido
> get0("x", as.environment(teste))
[1] 1 2 3
> get0("y", as.environment(teste))
NULL
> get0("y", as.environment(teste), ifnotfound = "")
[1] ""
```

So, back to your example,

```
getme <- 
    function(x) 
        get0(
            x, 
            as.environment(samples), 
            ifnotfound = rep(0,nrow(samples))
        )
samples$r1 <- 
    ifelse(
        getme("s1") == 1,
        "s1", 
        ifelse(
            getme("s2") == 1,
            "s2",
            ifelse(
                getme("s3") == 1,
                "s3",
                ifelse(
                    getme("s4") == 1,
                    "s4",
                    ifelse(
                        getme("s5") == 1,
                        "s5",
                        ifelse(
                            getme("s6") == 1,
                            "s6",       
                            "99"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

gives the desired result

```
  s1 s2 s3 s5 s6 r1
1  1  2  3  4  5 s1
2  2  3  4  1  5 s5
3  4  1  2  3  5 s2
4  2  1  4  3  5 s2
5  3  4  1  2  5 s3
6  4  3  2  1  5 s5
7  2  3  1  4  5 s3
8  3  5  4  2  1 s6
```

So, to sum up, what you wanted is neither practical nor elegant, but is feasible.